# Show that the product topology on $X \times Y$ is the same as the metric topology, where the metric is the product metric

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Any help on the following problem would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Given metrics $d$ and $e$ on sets $X$ and $Y$, let $f$ be the product metric on $X \times Y$. So $f((x_{1},y_{1}),(x_{2},y_{2}))=max\{d(x_{1},x_{2}),e(y_{1},y_{2})\}$. Prove that the product topology $\mathcal{T}_{d} \times \mathcal{T}_{e}$ on $X \times Y$ is the same as $\mathcal{T}_{f}$.

Do we define a base $\mathcal{B}=\{U \times V : U \in \mathcal{T}_{d}, V \in \mathcal{T}_{e}\}$ and prove that it's associated topology $\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{B}}$ is in fact $\mathcal{T}_{f}$?

Comment: You show that two topologies are the same if the bases that they are generated from are the same

Comment: So the base for $\mathcal{T}_{d} \times \mathcal{T}_{e}$ is the $\mathcal{B}$ defined above and we have to show that this generates $\mathcal{T}_{f}$? How can you do this?

Comment: First you have to find what generates $T_f$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$B_f((x,y),\epsilon)= \{(a,b) |d(x,a)<\epsilon,e(y,b)<\epsilon\}=B_d(x,e\epsilon)\times B_e(y,\epsilon)$$

Comment: So for the metric $f$ on $X \times Y$, a base is $\mathcal{B}'=\{B_{d}(x,\epsilon) \times B_{e}(y,\epsilon): x \in X, y \in Y, r>0\}?$

Comment: Yes , but that won't be that logical. As I mentioned in my answer take an open set and show that it is also there in the product topology. Now take a set in the basis of product topology and show that it is there in your metric product. Anyways that is the basis for the metric topology

Comment: OK I think I have done one way. Since $U$ is open in $X$, for $x \in U$   $\exists$  $ r_{x}>0$ such that $B_{d}(x,r_{x})\subset U$. Similarly, $B_{e}(y,r_{y})\subset V$. Now let $(x,y) \in U \times V$ and consider $B_{f}((x,y),r)$ where $r>max\{r_{x},r_{y}\}$. Then for $(x',y') \in B_{f}((x,y),r)$, $f((x,y),(x',y'))<r$ so $d(x,x')<r$ and $e(y,y')<r$. Thus $x' \in U$ and $y' \in V$, and $(x',y') \in U \times V$. So $B_{f}((x,y),r)\subset U \times V$ and $U \times V$ is open in $\mathcal{T}_{f}$.

Comment: Actually, I should take $r<min\{r_{x},r_{y}\}$ right?

Comment: Yes you should.

Comment: OK for the other way, given $B_{f}((x,y),r)$ in $\mathcal{T}_{f}$ and $(x',y') \in B_{f}((x,y),r)$, we need to find an open set in $\mathcal{T}_{d} \times \mathcal{T}_{e}$ containing $(x',y')$ and that is contained in $B_{f}((x,y),r)$. How do we do this?

Comment: I have given you the hint in my answer

Comment: So as $B_{f}((x,y),r)=B_{d}(x,r) \times B_{e}(y,r)$ it is in the base for the product topology?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29119/discussion-between-remember-me-and-jackwo).